# How to disable browser scrolling in mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I have simple html file with an iframe inside, I've been trying to stop my browser from scrolling in both documents, yet this seem to work ometimes and sometimes it doesn't.

I've applied several listeners to stop interaction (ON BOTH DOCUMENTS), this one in the code being my last one. I've changed mousmove, mousestart, mouseover, touchstart, {return false;} instead of stopPropagation(), etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Stand Alone Game Version</title>
    <!-- TODO: Generar un ratio o factor para el tamaño del juego -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">   
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();
            console.log("TOUCHING!");
            document.addEventListener("touchmove", function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();
            console.log("MOVING!");
            return false});
            return false});
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {background-color:#b0c4de;}    
        .game-container
        {
            overflow: hidden;           
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game-container" class="game-container" style="display: block;">
        <iframe class ="gameframe" src="http://www.emol.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width=512 height=2000></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now I'm testing with a Nexus 7.

Is there a stable solution for this?

Best regards.

Comment: Try detect mobile browser by js and add css class with overflow hidden for same elements

Comment: @user2257149 AFAIK overflow: hidden attends rendering, not scrollabillity, you can still scroll overflow hidden pages in mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying **game-container** on the body. If it is not working, you can also try to insert these lines in  **game-container**

```
 max-width:100%;
 max-height:100%;
```